# Transparent terminal in JWM

Tags: linux, terminal

How can I (in order of preference):

a) make lxterminal fake transparency work in JWM
b) make another lightweight terminal transparent or fake-transparent in JWM
c) make trasparent ONLY the terminal in JWM using compton

In the lxterminal configuration file I tried to set bgtransparent=true and bgalpha=(various integers) but it didn't work. Also in the edit/configuration menu there is not option for setting transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved this one myself. I'll post here in case anyone has the same question.

These are the steps I've taken:

1. installed: compton, transset-df, devilspie
2. set all opacity parameters in JWM to 1.0 (that means putting the line:

   ```
   <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
   ```

   in the .jwmrc config file for each element like windows style, menu, etc.) so they won't be transparent
3. created the file .devilspie/opacity.ds in my home dir
4. run command

   ```
   $devilspie -a
   ```

   in terminal to find identifier for lxterminal
5. put the following code in the opacity.ds file:

   ```
   ( if
   ( or
   ( contains ( window_class ) "Gvim" )
   ( contains ( application_name ) "lxterminal" )
   )
   ( begin
   ( spawn_async (str "transset-df -i " (window_xid) " 0.85" ))
   )
   )
   ```

   where 0.85 is the opacity level (can be anything from 0.00 to 1.00)
6. Added the following commands to .jwmrc:

   ```
   <StartupCommand>compton </StartupCommand>
   <StartupCommand>devilspie -a </StartupCommand>
   ```

If you use Conky, it has its own transparency setting in its config file.
Further information can be found at:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Per-application_transparency